# How to get an image from queued request body (Workbox PWA)

Tags: javascript, axios, progressive-web-apps, workbox-webpack-plugin, background-sync

I am using [Workbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/) in my PWA. If app is offline and image posting request fails - it is [automatically added to IndexedDB](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync/#adding-a-request-to-the-queue).

```
    const post = (file: File) => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("image", file);
        axios.post('http://some.com/upload', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(...)
```

I want to show user all images of queued requests in offline mode. How i get requests:

```js
import { openDB } from 'idb';
const db = await openDB('workbox-background-sync');
const queuedRequests = await db.getAllFromIndex('requests', 'queueName');
```

Body of request is ArrayBuffer [(how request is stored in IndexedDB is showed on the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zlSC.png). I don't understand how to "extract" image and pass it to
`createObjectURL( imageBlob )`.

If i decode body like this:

```
let view = new Uint8Array(body);
let bodyAsString = new TextDecoder().decode(view);
```

I got post body which contains image bytes after *"image/png\r\n\r\n"*:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryfc7IW9qvYqE2SdSm\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="1.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n�PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\...
```

I don't think that parsing payload using regexp, then encoding it is a good approach. How can this be done?

Comment: `I tried to pass this ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array and and Blob constructors. I tried to pass queued request to Request constructor and call its methods` - Can you show us how you tried to do that, and whether there were any errors?

Comment: @FiddlingAway ```let view = new Uint8Array(body); let bodyAsString = new TextDecoder().decode(view);``` I got payload ```------WebKitFormBoundaryfc7IW9qvYqE2SdSm\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="1.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n�PNG\r\n\x1A\n\x00\...``` what should i do next?

Comment: What do you see inside the `Chrome DevTools > Application > IndexedDB > workbox-background-sync > requests` ? Is your request stored there? If it is, can you edit your question, and add things like: database name, object store name?